# PIVOT table returning all null data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid,
    FORMAT(datecreated, 'yyyy-MM') AS purchasemonth,
    COALESCE(amount + tip, 0) AS amt
  FROM invoice
) AS SourceTable
```

which produces output like this:

[image]

And this pivot query in which I am trying to sum over each month:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  COALESCE([2016-08-01], 0) AS [2016-08-01],
  COALESCE([2016-09-01], 0) AS [2016-09-01]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid,
    FORMAT(datecreated, 'yyyy-MM') AS purchasemonth,
    COALESCE(amount + tip, 0) AS amt
  FROM invoice
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amt)
  FOR purchasemonth IN ([2016-08-01], [2016-09-01])
) AS PivotTable
```

which produces output like this:

[image]

There is no NULL data at all in the original query's output.  The PIVOT query's output is nothing but null data (coalesced to 0).  But I can't figure out why the PIVOT is not summing the data as I expected.  I'm expecting there to be no NULL data in the PIVOT output either.

How can I fix the query to behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PurchaseMonth` in your *Derived Table* is a *String* without *DAYs* in it and you are comparing it to a *Date* with days in it for the values/column names:

So the main issue is this line:

```
FOR purchasemonth IN ([2016-08-01], [2016-09-01])
```

TO

```
FOR purchasemonth IN ([2016-08], [2016-09])
```

Once you change that you would need to change the `COALESCE()` statements too

and you should get what you want.

```
SELECT
  userid,
  COALESCE([2016-08], 0) AS [2016-08-01],
  COALESCE([2016-09], 0) AS [2016-09-01]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid,
    FORMAT(datecreated, 'yyyy-MM') AS purchasemonth,
    COALESCE(amount + tip, 0) AS amt
  FROM invoice
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amt)
  FOR purchasemonth IN ([2016-08], [2016-09])
) AS PivotTable
```

If you want the `01` to remain for days then simply change up the `Derived Table` definition to be a date or include the day in the format

So if you want to go this route change this line:

`FORMAT(datecreated, 'yyyy-MM') AS purchasemonth,`

To

`DATEADD(day,1-DAY(datecreated),datecreated) AS purchasemonth,`

you could also use this

`FORMAT(datecreated, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS purchasemonth,`

But `FORMAT` has performance impacts that you have no reason to introduce if you don't need to.

```
SELECT
  userid,
  COALESCE([2016-08-01], 0) AS [2016-08-01],
  COALESCE([2016-09-01], 0) AS [2016-09-01]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid,
    DATEADD(day,1-DAY(datecreated),datecreated) AS purchasemonth,
    COALESCE(amount + tip, 0) AS amt
  FROM invoice
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amt)
  FOR purchasemonth IN ([2016-08-01], [2016-09-01])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: that was embarrassing, that was essentially just a typo that i missed.  tyvm.